# Website indexing issue on Google Search Console: "Processing data, please check again in a day or so" status persists for a month

Tags: indexing, web-crawler, google-search, google-search-console

I've been facing difficulties with indexing my [website](https://ilparcocasavacanze.it/),
on Google Search Console. Despite waiting for a significant period, the Overview section consistently shows a "Processing data" message, instructing me to check back in a day or so. This issue has persisted for over a month now. Furthermore, when I navigate to other tabs within Google Search Console, no information or data is displayed.

What I have done:

1. Checked the robots.txt file to ensure it is not blocking search
   engine crawlers.
2. Added Sitemap.xml file to ensure the bot-crawleing
   for my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding metatags in the index.html file that would allow google's crawler bots to find my website and index it.

Comment: Which metatags did you add?

Comment: Check them by inspecting the homepage <meta name="keywords" content=" ... "

Answer (score 0):

it might be beacuse you are using www with your website.
just try to remove www from your Gooogle Search Console and just add https://yourdomain.com not https://www.yourdomain.com

Comment: Where do you see the www.  part in the url?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have the same problem in https://shira-dayan.co.il
which meta tags show I add?